# Centralized logging with Kafka and ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, kibana

There are more than 50 Java applications (They are not microservices, so we don't have to worry about multiple instance of the service). Now my architect designed a solution to get the log files and feed into a kafka topic and from kafka feed it into logstash and push it to elastic search so we can view the logs in kibana. Now I am new to Kafka and ELK stack. Will someone point me to a right direction on how to do this task. I learnt that Log4J and SLF4J can be configured to push the logs to kafka topic. 
1. Now how to consume from kafka and load it into logstash? Do I have to write a kafka consumer or we can do that just by configuration?
2. How logstash will feed the logs to elastic search?
3. How can I differentiate all the 50 application logs, do i have to create topic for each and every application?

I put the business problem, now I need step by step expert advice. - Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what your architect has laid out for you can be divided into two major components based upon their function (on architecture level);

1. Log Buffer (**Kafka**)
2. Log Ingester (**ELK**)

   [Java Applications] **=====>** [Kafka] **------>** [ELK]

If you study **ELK** you would feel like it is sufficient for your solution and **Kafka** would appear surplus. However, **Kafka** has important role to play when it comes to scale. When many of your Java applications would send logs to **ELK**, **ELK** may become overloaded and break.
To avoid **ELK** from overload your architect has setup a buffer (**Kafka**). **Kafka** will receive logs from applications and queue it up in case ELK is under load. In this way you do not break **ELK** and also you do not loose logs when **ELK** is struggling.

Answers to your questions in the same order;
(1) Logstash has 'input' plugins that can be used to setup a link between Kafka & Logstash. Read on Logstash and its plugins.

i- [Logstash Guide or Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html)
ii- [Input Plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html) (scroll down to find Kafka plugin)

(2) Logstash will feed received logs to Elasticsearch by **Output plugin** for Elasticsearch. [See Logstash output plugin for Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html).

(3) I may not be spot-on on this, but I think you would be able to filter & distinguish the logs at the Logstash level once you receive it from Kafka. You could apply tags or fields to each log message on reception. This additional info will be used by Elasticsearch to distinguish the applications from one another.

**Implementation Steps**

As somebody who is new to Kafka & ELK follow these steps to your solution;

**Step 1**: Start by setting up ELK first. Once you do that you would be able to see how logs are visualized and will become clearer how end solution may look like.

[Guide to ELK Stack](https://logz.io/learn/complete-guide-elk-stack/#intro)

**Step 2**: Setup Kafka to link your application logs to ELK.

**Caveats:**

1. You may find ELK to have some decent learning curve. Much time is required to understand how each element in the ELK stack works and what is its individual configuration and languages are.
2. To have deep understanding of ELK use the local deployment path where you setup ELK on your system. Avoid the cloud ELK services for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Logstash has a [kafka](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html) input and an [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) output, so this is configuration on the logstash side. You could differentiate the application using configuration on the log4j side (although using many topics is another possibility).